# regex for matching string before and after a given string

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract text before and after the matching pattern.

```
ex: [2018-03-12 22:04:51,324] BEFORE string<ID:1234><PID:345678>AFTER string
```

I would like to get this information:

```
message: BEFORE string AFTER string
my_id: 1234
my_pid: 345678
```

I tried:

```
^\[(?P<time>\d+\-\d+\-\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)](?P<my_id>[^>]+)><\w+:(?P<my_pid>\d+)[^>\n]*>(?P<message>[\S\s\r\n]*)$
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly are you trying to extract? Are you trying to extract ID and PID?

Comment: message: BEFORE string AFTER string
my_id: 1234
my_pid: 345678

Comment: And are you doing it in java? please tag the language used.

Comment: is the `ex:` in the line or the line starts with `[20..`?

Comment: line starts with [20..

Comment: `\[[0-9-:, ]+](.+)\<ID:(\d+)><PID:(\d+)>(.+)` does this work?

Comment: group1 and group4 should be together.  i cannot use any concats outside of the regex

Comment: then it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to understand your question. You want to get ID and PID from this expression, So I prefer to get these two value with two matches.

[**Test**](https://regex101.com/r/AkGcKI/2)

```
r"[P]{0,1}ID:([0-9]{1,})"
```

**Result:**

- Match 1

> Full match `ID:1234`
>
> Group 1.  `1234`

- Match 2

> Full match `PID:345678`
>
> Group 1.  `345678`

Comment: extracting IDs was not an issue.  But i want the message before the ids and after the ids.  From this string, I would like to extract "BEFORE string After string" in one group. [2018-03-12 22:04:51,324] BEFORE string<ID:1234><PID:345678>AFTER string